# Method paratemers refactoring in software-design

Tags: architecture, refactoring, software-design

I guess the question applies to any OO-Language.
According to software-design guidelines(1), fields (= variables here), what comes together in the method parameter list , let it be for example

```
String bikeName;
Wheel wheel1;
Wheel wheel2;
```

Used in the lots methods together, for example

```
firstMethod(String bikeName, Wheel wheel1, Wheel wheel2) ...
secondMethod(String bikeName, Wheel wheel1, Wheel wheel2) ...
```

according to softwaredesign, is is better to refactor the code to have the Class Bike with this fields, and methods:

```
firstMethod(Bike bike)
secondMethod(Bike bike)
```

This operation is trivial and can even be done automated to any code by a one-button click refactoring function.

Consider the case, firstMethod has following in his body:

```
firstMethod(Bike bike){

Wheel rwheel = bike.getRearWheel();
int somePower = rwheel.getPower(); //whatever

secondMethod(bike);
}


secondMethod(Bike bike){
...
Wheel rwheel = bike.getRearWheel();
// or even:
int somePower = rwheel.getPower(); //whatever


}
```

But in the secondMethod, the bike.getRearWheel() or further rwheel.getSpeed() is **called** **again**. 
In order to do not call the same methods twice (also a software-design guideline), one could change a method to

```
secondMethod(Bike bike, int someSpeed )...
```

But this is can become cumbersome, especially in the real case with lost of variables and is against the guideline (1).
What variabt would you choose in the praxis?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achive. The given example is confusing and the question contains some mistakes what makes it hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

guidelines are not solutions and cannot cover every situation. My (strictly personal) recommendation is to try it as follows:

```
firstMethod(Bike bike){
    ... // other stuff
    int somePower = bike.getRearWheek().getPower();
    ...
    secondMethod(bike, somePower);
    ...
}
```

Then define:

```
secondMethod(Bike bike){
    secondMethod(bike, -1);
}

secondMethod(Bike bike, int knownPower){
    ...
    int somePower = (knownPower < 0)? bike.getRearWheel().getPower() : knownPower;
    ...
}
```

Or along those lines, anyway.

Comment: Hallo, Achim ))
thanks, but sorry, you did not fully understand the question.
As i Sayd, of cource i know about defalut-values approach.
One of the points **HERE** is , you may not have here a call
`secondMethod(Bike bike, int knownPower)`
where knownPower in an **independent** variable (from Bike) , 
because then, a user  or even a code creator)) could (by mistake) call (anyBike, anyValue), and this would run wrong because _value_ is not to ` bike.getRearWheel().getPower()` related.
The design of software must also prevent such mistakes.

Comment: I have only answered the question as to what I would do in this situation. That is what was asked. In the end programming guidelines can only achieve so much. You cannot predict or prevent incorrect usage. The user of a method must make sure he/she knows what it does.